# Odd NSXMLParserDelegate method... bug thing

Tags: iphone, if-statement, nsxmlparser

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString
*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary
*)attributeDict {

    NSLog(@"%@", elementName); // returns the current element name

    if (elementName == @"group") { // never called
        NSLog(@"%@", elementName);
        self.group = [[Group alloc] init];
    }
    ...
}
```

What exactly is going on here? The `NSLog()` outside the `if` is getting called and returning exactly the `elementName` I need to make the `if` statement true, but the `NSLog()` within the `if` statement is never called? What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't compare nsstrings with `==`,

try

`if([elementName isEqualToString:@"group"])`